# MVVMCross WinStore Add item to XAML defined with DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, mvvmcross

So I have a number of items defined in my view-model that I want to then add to my view in XAML. Since these items are numerous, I was trying to reduce a bit of redundancy by creating a datatemplate defined for the custom class in the view-model, then nest them in the XAML. What I have looks like this so far.

```
    <Page.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="CommandCenterTemplate"  >
        <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance core:ComboBoxCommandCenter}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Width="150" Content="{Binding Title}" Command="{Binding OnClickCommand}"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" SelectedValue="{Binding Selected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">Combat</x:String>
</Page.Resources>
```

and previously had itemized each of these in the XAML in-line like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation ="Horizontal">
                <Button Width="150" Content="Skills" Command="{Binding SkillCommand}"></Button>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SkillOptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding SkillSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
```

with the class defined in the View-Model looking as such:

```
public class ComboBoxCommandCenter : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private IEnumerable<string> _options;
    private string _title;

    public ComboBoxCommandCenter(string title,IEnumerable<string> options, Action<string> action)
    {
        _options = options;
        OnClickAction = action;

    }
    private Action<string> OnClickAction { get; set; }
    public string Selected { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Options
    {
        get { return _options; }
    }

    public ICommand OnClickCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => OnClickAction(Selected)); }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

So I want to be able to replace the stack panel object with an instance of the class in the view-model thats aleady been instantiated.

```
public class CombatViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
       public ComboBoxCommandCenter SaveCenter { get; private set; }
```

public CombatViewModel(ICharacterService character)
            : base(character)
        {
            SaveCenter = new ComboBoxCommandCenter("Save",MyCharacter.Actions.SaveOptions(), MyCharacter.Actions.Save);
        }
    }

So is there a way to then place some code in the XAML to look something like

```
<core:ViewModel.SaveCenter />
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, then there isn't a list of ComboBoxCommandCenters, but only one. And your question is how to show this one ComboBoxCommandCenter. In this case you can use:

```
<ContentControl 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommandCenterTemplate}" 
    Content="{Binding pathToYourViewModel_SaveCenter}"
    />
```

Update: Answering the question in the comment:

> I have multiple c omboboxes to add. When I state the content does or can xaml pull a template based on its class? This almost gets into perhaps needing a separately written control perhaps vs simply defining it in the inline xaml I wonder.

A little simpler than creatig a new Control:

Instead of setting ContentTemplate you can set the ContentTemplateSelector. To select the template in code with a ContentTemplateSelector, you'd have to inherit from [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and add your selection logic by overriding SelectTemplate().

The much more elegant solution would be "implicit DataTemplates" which make XAML select a default DataTemplate based on the data type. But this is only available in WPF. In Windows Store apps such behavior is only available to Styles (via TargetType).

Comment: Thank you. Ill give this a try. I have multiple   c omboboxes to add. When I state the content does or can xaml pull a template based on its class? This almost gets into perhaps needing a separately written control perhaps vs simply defining it in the inline xaml I wonder.